# Special character from FTP directory

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

i´m using the black raccoon class for ftp sessions. getting the content of a FTP directory  like this

```
arrayHelper.FTPFileName = [file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName]
```

and writing into nsmutablearray

i have some folders with special character like this on the ftp share:

"Heino - Mit Freundlichen Gr\U00b8ssen (Deluxe Edition) (2013) - 320"

How can i convert the string?

i´ve try´ed the following:

```
NSString *uncodedName = [file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName];
        NSLog(@"Uncoded Name is %@",uncodedName);
        arrayHelper.FTPFileName = [NSString stringWithCString:[uncodedName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                     encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Coded Name is %@",arrayHelper.FTPFileName);
```

but returns nil...

NSLog:

[7344:c07] Uncoded Name is Heino - Mit Freundlichen Gr¸ssen (Deluxe Edition) (2013) - 320
[7344:c07] Coded Name is (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can see in the source code of [CFFTPStream.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128/FTP/CFFTPStream.c?txt)
that `CFFTPStream` interprets all file names on the FTP server in the "Mac OS Roman" encoding. Your FTP server seems to use Windows encoded file names, which are therefore wrongly converted to Unicode in `CFFTPStream`.

But you can reverse the process with

```
NSString *uncodedName = [file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName];
NSData *data = [uncodedName dataUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
arrayHelper.FTPFileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I answered the question even if I can't stand Heino music :-)

Comment: THX a lot! works perfect! ...but my next problem is writing back the string to a nsmutablearray (used for browsing the ftp share) returns me a "Heino - Mit Freundlichen Gr\U00fcssen (Deluxe Edition) (2013) - 320"   ..... me too with the heino music, but he´s covering rock bands in the new album :-)

Comment: @HugoBoss: The NSLog or debugger output often prints special characters using escape sequences, `\U00fc` *is* "ü".

Comment: yes, you´re right! logging just the filename is ok. I need to convert the string back for a ftp request? get an error with the ü in the name..

Comment: @HugoBoss: Yes probably. (I know a bit about encodings, but nothing about the BlackRaccoon project.) You can swap the encodings in the above code to convert back to the encoding needed for the FTP request. Or you can remember both strings and use the converted string only for display, and the original string for requests.

Comment: tried both methods without luck :-( can´t even use the original string to browse, and the back converted also not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26300/discussion-between-martin-r-and-hugoboss)

Comment: changing the kCFStringEncodingUTF8 in the brrequest.m to kcFStringEncodingWindowsLatin1 was my solution! of course in combination with martin´s reverse process. Martin thank you very much for your help!!